# VBA Filtering by rows with the highest value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that contains data multiple versions of the same file. Now, I would need the most recent version of the file which has the high number after a " - " 
for example

202674-15.xls

202674-15.xls

202674-15.xls

202674-15.xls

202674-15.xls

202674-15.xls

202674-15.xls

202674-18.xls

202674-18.xls

202674-18.xls

202674-18.xls

202674-18.xls

I have considerable amount of files like this, and they're not all of the same, otherwise, I would just find the max value.The way i was thinking is making an array to read all the files and then make different arrays for the files types that begin with the same number before the "-" and then find the max value within these files and keep the set of rows that have this max value and filter it.  I'm new to vba, so I have no idea where I would begin, or what questions I would ask, so I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Could you not just sort?

Comment: What you could do is to read the file names, parse them and split the name into two parts. Type and version. This can be done in any language of your choice, including power shell, c#, or vbscript or even shell script, what have you tried and did not work?

Answer (score 0):

The below assumes your file names are in column A.

Put this formula in column B `=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)` and this formula in column C `=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,FIND(".xls",A1)-FIND("-",A1)-1)` and then sort columns ABC by column B, Values, A to Z then add a level to sort by Column C, Values, A to Z (or Z to A if you want highest first).

This will sort all the files first by the digits before "-" and then by the digits after "-".